# SSH Connection refuse after changing port

Tags: ssh, centos7

I am connecting to CentOS7 minimal installation machine in a LAN (192.168.1.33).
I have changed the ssh port vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 17 Port 1234

after restarting the sshd service the connection is refused

```
ssh  demo@192.168.1.33 -p 1234
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.33 port 1234: Connection refused
```

I have disabled SELinux and router-firewall but still having problem.
Though if I change back to port 22 I can login again.

Is there any other configuration to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you remotely connect to the server another way? If so, once you get in, run `sudo netstat -plutn`.

You should see at least one entry for sshd. If you don't, sshd isn't running. You can install it via `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

If you do, is the port under 'Local Address' for the sshd line 1234? This will tell you if you successfully changed the port configuration.

Hope that helps!